# Return value from callback in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, callback

I have a function in typescrypt in file Service.ts:

```
export const doCallAuth = (username, password) => {
    var auth = new Auth({
        url: '...',

      });

      var status;

      auth.authenticate(username, password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          status = 'no';

        } else if (!user.uid) {
          console.log("user not found Error");
          status = 'no';
        } else if (user.uid) {
          console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
          status = 'yes';
        }
      });

      return status;
}
```

I call this method by :

```
var result = Service.doCallAuth('test', 'test');
```

**And variable result is undefined**

I don't know why **result** is undefined

Can anybody help me out ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you are getting undefined as the authenticate is an async function and you are returning the status immediately after calling the async function.

Comment: @Sohail : So How I can fix ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise or callback patterns

**1. Promise**

```
export const doCallAuth = (username, password) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var auth = new Auth({ url: "..." });
    auth.authenticate(username, password, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (!user.uid) {
        reject(new Error("user not found Error"));
      } else if (user.uid) {
        console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
        resolve(user);
      }
    });
  });
};

Service.doCallAuth("test", "test")
  .then(user => {
    console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

**2. Callback**

```
export const doCallAuthCallBack = (username, password, callback) => {
  var auth = new Auth({ url: "..." });
  auth.authenticate(username, password, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else if (!user.uid) {
      callback(new Error("user not found Error"));
    } else if (user.uid) {
      callback(null, user);
    }
  });
};

Service.doCallAuthCallBack("test", "test", (err, user) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
  }
});
```

Comment: It's working fine.Can you writing by Async / Await ? :)

Comment: Just change the function call to `const result = await Service.doCallAuth("test", "test")`, Promises handle async/await pattern, and wrap the await call by try/catch pattern to catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 export const doCallAuth = (username, password, callback) => {
        var auth = new Auth({
            url: '...',
        });
        var status;
        auth.authenticate(username, password, callback);
    }
    var result;
    Service.doCallAuth('test', 'test', function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            status = 'no';
        } else if (!user.uid) {
            console.log("user not found Error");
            status = 'no';
        } else if (user.uid) {
            console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
            status = 'yes';
        }
        result = status;
    });
```

Comment: it's not working, result is undefined.

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please try that.

Comment: when you are calling Service.doCallAuth at that time pass the callback function. Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from AJAX call need to Use `async` and `await`

```
    export const doCallAuth = async function(username, password) => {
        var auth = new Auth({
            url: '...',

          });

          var status;

          auth.authenticate(username, password, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              status = 'no';

            } else if (!user.uid) {
              console.log("user not found Error");
              status = 'no';
            } else if (user.uid) {
              console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
              status = 'yes';
            }
            return status;
          });


    }
```

call this method by :

```
var result = await  Service.doCallAuth('test', 'test');
```

Comment: It's still not working, status is undefined :)

Comment: @JavaDevBeginner I have update my code. please check. If any problem please let me know.

Comment: still not working :)